# Build a Frequency Table from a Dataset

Tags: dataset

How can the Mathematica 11.3 module below be improved (it builds a frequency table)?  The data source is a Dataset object (dbase) and the row/column variables are respectively rowDIN and colDIN.  Here the table entries would give the grade distribution within subject.

Dataset's documentation has an example that suggests a solution (see the line titanic[GroupBy["sex"],GroupBy["class"],ratio,"survived"]).  Although I've tweaked this to get the desired table, it works because the table has no zeros.  When applied to another database whose table would have zeros, Mathematica doesn't return a table -- that's why I use Count below.

There must be an easier way, and hopefully someone here knows it.  Thanks.

```
myTable[dbase_, rowDIN_, colDIN_] := Module[{
columns = Sort@Normal@DeleteDuplicates@dbase[[All, colDIN]],
group,
X = GroupBy[dbase, rowDIN]},   

X = (group = #; {group[[1, rowDIN]], 
    Count[Normal@group[[All, colDIN]], #] & /@ columns}) & /@ X;
X = X // Normal // Normal // Last /@ # &;
Grid@Prepend[Flatten /@ X, Prepend[columns, rowDIN]]];

myTable[schoolInfo, "Subject", "Grade"]
```

where

```
schoolInfo = Dataset@{<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
"Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
"Grade" -> "B"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
"Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
"Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
"Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
"Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>}
```

(J.M., I'm sorry for posting the wrong dataset a moment ago.  The above is correct.)

Answer (score 5):

This is also a bit ugly, but at least it's short:

```
schoolInfo = Dataset @ {<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "B"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>,
                        <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>};

grades = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

schoolInfo[GroupBy["Subject"], 
           Lookup["Grade"] /* Counts /*
           (AssociationThread[grades, Lookup[#, grades, 0]] &)]
```

[image: derived dataset]

Comment: This is perhaps more readable (to my eyes at least): ``schoolInfo[GroupBy[Key["Subject"] ->Key["Grade"]], KeySort@Merge[{Counts[#], Thread[grades -> 0]}, First] &]``. Or perhaps this: ``schoolInfo[GroupBy[Key["Subject"] -> Key["Grade"]], KeySort@Join[AssociationThread[grades, 0], Counts[#]] &]``

Comment: Thanks J.M.  This was the "raw Mathematica" that I was looking for.  A friend (who has read these posts) has recently sent a merciful R solution that is tidy.

Answer (score 3):

`Transpose` imputes `Missing` expressions so can commute around it with a numerical imputation using `Replace`:

```
transposeCommute[f_]:=Query[Transpose]/*f/*Query[Transpose[#1]&]
```

> (note: as of 11.3 the slot lookup #1 is required to work around a bug
>   in Dataset typesystem)

Then:

```
infoTable = schoolInfo[GroupBy["Subject"], GroupBy["Grade"], Length][
 transposeCommute[Query[All,KeySort, Replace[_Missing :> 0]]]]
```

[image]

If you want to add additional grades that don't appear anywhere in the input, another function is useful:

```
appendIfNoKey[key_->f_][as_Association]:=If[KeyExistsQ[as,key],as,Append[as,{key->f}]]

appendIfNoKey[ruleList_List][as_Association]:=Query[Apply[RightComposition][Map[appendIfNoKey][ruleList]]][as]
```

Then, to pad grades "A" through "F":

```
infoTable[All, appendIfNoKey[Thread[{"A", "B", "C", "E", "F"} -> 0]]]
```

[image]

So while there are gaps in the language, workarounds for such generic patterns are often 1-liners. These functions are from a API of mostly 1-liners to be bundled w/ a data science book I'm writing.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is this a solution you are looking for, but you can use the package [CrossTabulate.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/CrossTabulate.m):

```
schoolInfo = 
  Dataset@{<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
     "Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "B"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
     "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
     "Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
     "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>};

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/CrossTabulate.m"]

MatrixForm[CrossTabulate[schoolInfo]]
```

[image]

I consider the making of contingency tables to be a fundamental operation. More detailed explanations are given in the blog post ["Contingency tables creation examples"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/contingency-tables-creation-examples/).

### Update (2018-04-05)

Because the answers of @alancalvitti and @J.M. provide extensions of the columns of the contingency table with all grades (from "A" to "F") here is code to do that extension for my answer above.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/SSparseMatrix.m"]

rct = ToSSparseMatrix[ct]
rct2 = ImposeColumnNames[rct, CharacterRange["A", "F"]]
MatrixForm[rct2]
```

[image]

(For details on `SSparseMatrix` see [SSparseMatrix.pdf](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/SSparseMatrix.pdf)(GitHub) or [this blog post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/rsparsematrix-for-sparse-matrices-with-named-rows-and-columns/).)

Comment: Thank you, Anton.  I'll spend time looking at what you've created and then will use it.  Although I was looking for ideas that J.M. and Dulgerci have provided, using your *.m file is the most expedient approach.  I'll also look for other work you've created.  See you again at WTC2018.

Answer (score 1):

This might be ugly but here how I did.

```
schoolInfo = {<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "B"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
    "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
    "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>};

val = GatherBy[Values@schoolInfo, First];

Grid[Join @@ {{{"Subject", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}}, 
   Table[Flatten@{val[[i, 1, 1]], 
      Map[Length, 
       Cases[val[[i]], #] & /@ {{_, "A"}, {_, "B"}, {_, "C"}, {_, 
          "D"}, {_, "E"}, {_, "F"}}, 2]}, {i, Length@val}]}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> Black}, {2 -> Black}}]
```

> \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
>  \text{Subject} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} & \text{F} \\
> \hline
>  \text{XYZ} & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{ABC} & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}

**Edit** Probably there is more fancy and easy way to do it. This is the first time I am working with `Dataset`

```
schoolInfo = {<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "B"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
    "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
    "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>};
val = GatherBy[Values@schoolInfo, First];
val2 = Flatten@{"Subject", 
    DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@val[[All, All, 2]]};

Grid[Join @@ {{val2}, 
   Table[Flatten@{val[[i, 1, 1]], 
      Map[Length, Cases[val[[i]], #] & /@ ({_, #} & /@ Rest@val2), 
       2]}, {i, Length@val}]}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> Black}, {2 -> Black}}]
```

> \begin{array}{c|ccc}
>  \text{Subject} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} \\
> \hline
>  \text{XYZ} & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
>  \text{ABC} & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
> \end{array}

Here is different dataset:

```
schoolInfo = {<|"Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "XYZ", "Grade" -> "B"|>, <|"Subject" -> "XYZ", 
    "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", 
    "Grade" -> "C"|>, <|"Subject" -> "ABC", "Grade" -> "A"|>, <|
    "Subject" -> "DEF", "Grade" -> "D"|>};
```

> \begin{array}{c|cccc}
>  \text{Subject} & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} \\
> \hline
>  \text{XYZ} & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{ABC} & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
>  \text{DEF} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}

Comment: Thank you, Okkes.  Although I was looking for J.M.'s solution, your approach was very instructive (we're both learning how to use Datasets -- your code reinforced some concepts that I better appreciate now).